# TPS53627 - Pin details and connection

Tags: power-supply, step-down

I am trying to use TPS53627(https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps53627.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1628703320954&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Ftps53627).. to power my IC(VDD) which needs 0.8V and 15A , The datasheet does not contain any details on PIN are how it should be connected to my IC's VDD. If anyone have used TPS53627 ,Please let me know how this can be included in my circuit to power my Chip.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an Intel application, TI cannot share the designs and datasheets without making sure an NDA is in place. If you email vr@list.ti.com they can check to make sure everything checks out.

> https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps53626.pdf?ts=1628708031068
>
> https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/810304/tps53627-pmic-for-intel-cpu-vr13

This applies to all the Intel designs like the one above.

Comment: Tony - Hi, As I've reminded you twice in the last few days, [this site rule](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) requires that when you copy information from an external source, you **must** properly reference it. In this case, your answer is a copy & paste from [here on the TI E2E site](https://e2e.ti.com/support/power-management-group/power-management/f/power-management-forum/810304/tps53627-pmic-for-intel-cpu-vr13), so you **must** properly reference it and quote it (using the blockquote formatting, as shown in the site rule). Thanks.

Comment: I did not quote the text exactly and changed pronouns .